# Why are Index/ETF put option volumes generally higher than the call option volumes?

Tags: options, index, etf, liquidity, volume

It seems like put options on Index/ETFs generally have 50% more volume than call options, in terms of notionals. We don't see the same put/call volume ratios in single stocks.

Why is that the case?

I have thsi question after reading this article: https://www.ft.com/content/75587aa6-1f1f-4e9d-b334-3ff866753fa2

I have validated by spot checking the put/call volume ratios on Bloomberg terminal for a few major indexes and major tickers. This is indeed true. But I don't have an explanation

[image]

Comment: Over the last 2 days or in general (over a longer period of time)?

Comment: Same point here as @noob2 comment--what length of time are you looking at?  Your assertion is not even close to being accurate for equity or index options over a longer period of time.

Comment: @amdopt edited above. i don't have raw data, but I think Financial Times is rather reliable media source..

Comment: @noob2 see my added chart

Comment: Ah, ok. I didn't realize from your question that ETF volume was lumped in with Index volume. ETFs are much more than just index trackers.  I would get the raw data if I were you and deconstruct it.  I don't agree with blindly lumping them together for all purposes.  I guess it all depends on what you want your data to tell you though :)

Comment: @amdopt But why would ETF have more put volumes than call volumes?

Comment: Same reason that equity vs index options are so different.  Index ETFs will behave like indexes, non-index ETFs won't.

Comment: @amdopt I give FT the benefit of the doubt. Probably they mean "puts on broad indexes and puts on broad index ETFs". For example people trade puts on SPY in place of CBOE puts on S&P 500. Makes sense to include those SPY puts.

Comment: @noob2 To each their own. The benefit of the doubt as a reason for accepting a graphical representation of data is a foreign concept to me. That being said, I can't access the link without a subscription so perhaps there is a footnote or link to raw data that supports your assumption about what the author "probably means"?  Also, encouraging the OP to do some digging and not accept a chart at face value should be pretty standard advice.

Comment: @amdopt so initially you said my assertion was incorrect. Later you said it was because FT mingled index and non-index ETF options together. So I guess what you implied is that, for index and index ETF options, the put/call volumes are similar. But for non-index ETFs, they are off?

Comment: Would be interesting to see the ratio of index/ETF call-vs-put against the same for single stock (where optically call volumes equally and oppositely higher). Plenty of hypothetical explanations for this, if both are happening.... but are they really?

Answer (score 1):

Investors buy (and hold) more puts and pay up more for them for a few reasons. First, people fear downside more than they like upside as shown by Kahneman and Tversky (1979, 1992). Second, people may not be able to recover easily (or at all) from downside in the macroeconomy. In classical finance terms, if we think crises are different from times of stable growth, put options allow you to trade a state variable on macroeconomic distress (which the ICAPM says should be priced since it is valuable).

This is the whole point of the [Bondarenko (2014)](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=375784) expensive put options literature. See Figure 1 in the Bondarenko paper to see that puts having larger trading volume (and open interest) than calls is not new.

As for why this does not hold for single stock options: That is probably because an individual stock is an even noisier measure of the prospects for the macroeconomy. In fact, we see slightly more calls being traded. It could also arise from portfolio managers selling covered calls as an income-generating method which also conditionally rebalances their portfolios.

Answer (score 1):

It can mostly be attributed to portfolio insurance. Many investors (even mutual funds) are allowed to buy puts to hedge their downside risk in cash positions. I think the fact that mutual funds would buy puts increases the volume of puts vs calls with all else being equal. Since mutual funds are mostly positively correlated to the market, it makes sense to buy insurance on the whole market instead of individual stocks.

Answer (score 0):

Conventional wisdom is that clients buy puts on an index (e.g. SPX) to hedge their overall portfolio but buy calls on their single names and this explains differing p/c ratios for indices vs. single stocks.